# access token passed as query param becomes invalid on using request module

Tags: javascript, node.js, contentful

I am using the contentful (CMS platform) api to get the user details by userId by using `request` module. Here, the access-token is passed as query param which the system recognizes as invalid. But I am not sure if there is any wrong in the way I am passin the query param.I am pretty sure the token passed is valid as I can get the proper result using rest-client. Code is given below:

```
request.get(
  {
    url:
      "https://api.contentful.com/organizations/organizationId/users/userId",
    qs: {
      access_token:
        " CFPAT-xxxxxxxxxxxxxsxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx "
    },
    headers: {
      Authorization:
        "CFPAT-xxxxxxxxxxxxxsxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "x-contentful-enable-alpha-feature": "organization-user-management-api",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    method: "GET",
    json: true
  },
  function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
  }
);
```

`Error:`

```
{ requestId: 'e102c744950f39fdabad9ae942ac16ba',
  message:
   'The access token you sent could not be found or is invalid.',
  sys: { type: 'Error', id: 'AccessTokenInvalid' } }
```

Comment: That means you have an invalid token - check the token is correct.

Comment: I am sure the token is correct as I could get the response very well when I made request using rest client.